# pass non-english characters in dojo.io.iframe.send()

Tags: iframe, utf-8, character-encoding, dojo

I am using dojo.io.iframe.send() method to pass some parameters at server side. Some parameters can be non-ASCII.But iframe.send function does not provide charset as 'UTF-8'. So on server side I am not able to read correct non-ASCII characters.
How to handle this?

Thanks in advance!